# SocketTimeoutException Retrofit2 @POST requests

Tags: android, rest, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

Does anyone have any issues with Retrofit2 and `SocketTimeoutExceptions`? I can get my `@GET` requests to work, but I can't get a `@POST` request to work. Is this a known issue with Nexus devices? I can't find a solution anywhere--anything I do find, I've tried. Everything from setting `android:vmSafeMode="true"` in the Manifest to disabling `tcp_timestamp` on the server; I've also increased the read, write, and connect timeouts on the `OkHttpClient` to 45 seconds to see if that work work--but it didn't.

Does anyone have any tips?

Error looks like this:

```
10-16 20:26:00.745 15392-16552/io.havoc.todo D/OkHttp: --> POST http://redacted.amazonaws.com:3000/api/task/create http/1.1
10-16 20:26:00.745 15392-16552/io.havoc.todo D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json
10-16 20:26:00.745 15392-16552/io.havoc.todo D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 126
10-16 20:26:00.746 15392-16552/io.havoc.todo D/OkHttp: Accept: application/json
10-16 20:26:00.746 15392-16552/io.havoc.todo D/OkHttp: {"category":"","description":"Y","indexInList":4,"name":"Y","priority":"MEDIUM","user":"57a7bd24-ddf0-5c24-9091-ba331e486dc7"}
10-16 20:26:00.746 15392-16552/io.havoc.todo D/OkHttp: --> END POST (126-byte body)
//After 45 second timeout
10-16 20:26:25.757 15392-16552/io.havoc.todo D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP FAILED: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
10-16 20:26:25.811 15392-15392/io.havoc.todo E/(NewTaskActivityPresenter.java:49): Socket closed
```

Making the calls like so:

```
Task newTask = new Task(name, description, "", null, USER, 4, priority, null, null);

        Call<StandardTaskResponse> call = HavocService.getInstance().getHavocAPI().createNewTask(newTask);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<StandardTaskResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<StandardTaskResponse> call, Response<StandardTaskResponse> response) {
                LogUtil.v("Response message: " + response.message());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<StandardTaskResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
```

Comment: test your server using postman to make sure its Retrofit issue and not ur server

Comment: Don't think it's a server issue then. Postman works.